# How to pass a $_POST value to a php script from a ruby script

Tags: php, ruby, redmine

I need to run a cron job to add a svn repository using reposman.rb for Redmine. But we also have a php script (with an interface) that enable us to create repositories automaticly.

The php script receives a $_POST value, create the repos, sets permissions, assign some group for read and write access to the newly created repos.

My question is this:

1. how could I execute the php script, instead of the `svnadmin create` command in reposman.rb?
2. How can I give a $_POST parameter to the php script, so it could setup my svn repos correctly, using the php script.

Thanks

**Edit:**
Here are some example of what both scripts do.

***Ruby script:***

```
...
// Add the repos
system "svnadmin create #{path}"
...
```

***Php script:***

```
// Receive the name of the repos to add
$dir= $_POST["dir"]; 
// Do all the stuff with the permissions
$cmd= "sudo /usr/local/bin/createsvnrepo $dir";
system("$cmd", $retval);
...
```

Comment: Send http request to the PHP script and all data in POST will get parsed to $_POST array which will then be available in the script. Google "ruby curl".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, @Richard Knop's comment helped me more than any answer, I will answer my own question to help others.

I used [curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) to send a post to the php script.

***reposman.rb***

```
...
# Added at start of file.
require 'rubygems'
require 'curb'
...

# Replace the creation of repos from 
module SCM
    module Subversion
        def self.create(path)
            system_or_raise "svnadmin create #{path}"
        end
    end
    ...
end

# to 
module SCM
    module Subversion
        def self.create(path)
            Curl::Easy.http_post(
                "http://example.com/customCreaterepos.php", # Url to the php script
                Curl::PostField.content('reposName', path)) # Index of php $_POST in script
        end
    end
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to change the script, it should be getting its input data through a file or standard input. If it's not, you can write a wrapper script that picks data from file/stdin, populates `$_POST` with it (yes, PHP superglobals are writable) and calls the original script through `require`.

Answer (score 0):

Send http request to your script - $_POST is not intended to be initialized from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake a POST request to a PHP script with:
 (well, it's actually more "implement" than "fake")

```
exec "echo 'var=123_&data=...' | "
 " REQUEST_METHOD=POST CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded "
 " php-cgi"
```

Note that it really requires the `php-cgi` binary, not the normal -cli version. And you need to replicate **all** of the of the [CGI environment](http://www.w3.org/CGI/) variables. So it might be easier to just modify the existing script to accept $argv parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script from command line.
Something like this:

```
params = {'foo' => 'bar'} #etc
param_str = params.collect {|k,v| "#{CGI.escape(k)}=#{CGI.escape(v)}"}.join('&')
popen("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php", "w+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts(param_str)
  pipe.close_write
  res = pipe.read
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the php command line interface here (php_cli). You don't have $_POST, but you can provide arguments to pass to the php script. Do a system call from ruby to execute the php script (i dunno ruby so i only post the php part). In your php script start with the right shabang:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
```

The call should be something like:
./myscript.php -v=value1 -b=value2

Check the $_SERVER['argv'] for the values passed